# Create a list of matrix_world.translation for child object for n frames of animation

Tags: world, matrix

I want to save the location of a child object during the parent's animation.
My code populates the list with the last read value and none of the other values.
If I print the z location each iteration with the below I can see the correct value at each frame.
I don't understand why the list doesn't save individual vectors.

```
print(f'Z_Loc: {obj.matrix_world.translation[2]}')
```

[image]

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"]
start_frame =  20
translations = []

for frame in range(2):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(start_frame)
    translations.append(obj.matrix_world.translation)
    start_frame += 1

for num, ob in enumerate(translations):
    print(f'num: {num} matrix: {ob}')
```

Comment: Same as https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62549/python-deleting-objects-with-duplicate-location/62555#62555 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89906/context-frame-set-not-updating-every-time/89926#89926  `obj.matrix_world` is a reference, use instead `obj.matrix_world.copy()` (or copy the translation vector) to get a snap shot.

Comment: ... Or `matrix_world.to_translation()` in this case.

Comment: thankyou just what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

This gave the result I wanted.

```
translations.append(bpy.data.objects[obj.name].matrix_world.translation.copy())
```

Comment: No need to re reference : `translations.append(obj.matrix_world.translation.copy())`